# Socket client: don't get the full response with DataInputStream.readUTF()

Tags: java, sockets, client

I want to write a socket client to send a request to a server and get response back. It works, but not right. 
Here is my code:

```
public String send(final String data) {
        Socket client = null;
        String response = null;

        try {
            client = new Socket(this.host, this.port);

            final OutputStream outToServer = client.getOutputStream();
            final DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(outToServer);
            out.writeUTF(data);

            final InputStream inFromServer = client.getInputStream();
            final DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(inFromServer);
            response = in.readUTF();
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            this.log.error(e);
            this.log.error("Sending message to server " + this.host + ":" + this.port + " fail", e);
        } finally {
            if (client != null) {
                try {
                    client.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    this.log.error("Can't close socket connection to " + this.host + ":" + this.port, e);
                }
            }
        }
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(response)) return null;
        return response;
    }
```

The problem is: I didn't got the full response with `in.readUTF()`. I always got a response with the same length as the sent data's length (variable `data`).  I have tested with other GUI client and got the full response. So it's not a problem of the server.
*Does someone known, what i did wrong?*

**UPDATE**

Thanks EJP and Andrey Lebedenko. I think, my problems are the functions `writeUTF` and `readUTF`. So i have edited my code in the `try` block so:

```
        Charset charset = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1");
        final OutputStream outToServer = client.getOutputStream();
        final DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(outToServer);
        out.write(data.getBytes(charset));

        final InputStream inFromServer = client.getInputStream();
        final BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inFromServer, charset));
        response = in.readLine();
```

*And it worked now.*

Comment: Is the peer sending he data with `writeUTF()`?

Comment: Would it be possible to see the server part? `readUTF()` and `writeUTF()` definitely work without such a limitation. Just tested your code with my tcp server -- it works 100%. Need more input to suggest.

Comment: I can't. The server part isn't of me. I have tested with telnet and it worked. I don't think, that the server has a problem.

Comment: How do you know the server is sending data with `writeUTF()` if it isn't 'part' of you? How can it possibly work with a Telnet client, which doesn't use it either? This isn't making sense.

Comment: Sorry, it was false. I thought, that you ask about my client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it works with Telnet, as per your comment, the server isn't using `readUTF()`, so your `writeUTF()` is already wrong, and the server is therefore unlikely to be using `writeUTF()` either, which would make your `readUTF()` wrong as well. You can't use these methods arbitrarily: they can only interchange data between themselves.

I'll bet your GUI client that works doesn't use them either.

Comment: I have found, that the server is written in C. But i don't access to the server's code. What should i use instead of `readUTF` and `writeUTF`?

Comment: I works now. You are right. The problem was the functions `readUTF` and `writeUTF`. I have updated the right code.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what does server part do, it is kind of difficult (if possible at all) to trace down the root cause. So in the most honest hope that it will help I just share this code with which I've tested the fragment above.

```
package tcpsendreceive;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class SendReceive {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SendReceive.class.toString());

    private final String host;
    private final int port;

    private Server server;

    class Server extends Thread
    {
        private final ServerSocket serverSocket;
        public Server(ServerSocket s)
        {
            serverSocket = s;
        }

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            Socket connection;
            SendReceive.this.log.log(Level.INFO, "Server: DoubleEcho Server running on "+this.serverSocket.getLocalPort());
            try{
                do {
                    connection = this.serverSocket.accept();
                    SendReceive.this.log.log(Level.INFO, "Server: new connection from "+connection.getRemoteSocketAddress());
                    int b;
                    do {
                        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
                        String s = in.readUTF();

                        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
                        out.writeUTF(s+","+s); // echo it back TWICE

                        out.flush();
                        connection.shutdownOutput();
                        connection.close();
                    } while(!connection.isClosed());
                }
                while(true);
            }
            catch(IOException ioe)
            {
                SendReceive.this.log.log(Level.SEVERE, "IOException in server! - STOP", ioe);
            }
            finally {
                try{
                    this.serverSocket.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    SendReceive.this.log.log(Level.SEVERE, "IOException closing server! - FATAL", e);
                }
                try{
                    if(!connection.isClosed())
                      connection.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    SendReceive.this.log.log(Level.SEVERE, "IOException closing server! - FATAL", e);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public SendReceive(String host, int port)
    {
        this.host = host;
        this.port = port;
        try{
            this.server = new Server(new ServerSocket(this.port));
            this.server.start();
        }
        catch(IOException ioe)
        {
            this.log.log(Level.SEVERE, "IOException while creating server! - STOP", ioe);
        }
    }

    public String send(final String data) {
        Socket client = null;
        String response = null;

        try {
            client = new Socket(this.host, this.port);

            final OutputStream outToServer = client.getOutputStream();
            final DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(outToServer);
            out.writeUTF(data);

            final InputStream inFromServer = client.getInputStream();
            final DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(inFromServer);
            response = in.readUTF();
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            this.log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Sending message to server " + this.host + ":" + this.port + " fail", e);
        } finally {
            if (client != null) {
                try {
                    client.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    this.log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Can't close socket connection to " + this.host + ":" + this.port, e);
                }
            }
        }
        if(response == null || response.isEmpty()) 
            return null;

        return response;
    }    
}
```

Test-demo

```
package tcpsendreceive;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[]  args)
    {    
        String data = "AAABBB";
        SendReceive sr = new SendReceive("localhost", 5000);
        String res = sr.send(data);
        System.out.println("Sent: "+data);
        System.out.println("Received: "+res);
    }
}
```

Result (key part):

```
Sent: AAABBB
Received: AAABBB,AAABBB
```

Hope it helps.

*EDIT*
1. Corrected wrapper flush instead of socket stream flush. Still believe it is good practice to flush the stream wrapper before closing the socket.

2. Client socket closed in IOException block (since they aren't automatically closed on ServerSocket shutdown). Thanks @EJP

P.s. I should admit I was bit surprised by such an attention to the humble test server code, especially compared to other dirty tests we all have seen on SO. Flattered. :)

Comment: Thank you very much Andrey. I will check it tomorrow.

Comment: Flushing a socket's output stream does nothing. Flush before close is redundant. Shutdown before close is redundant. This code leaks sockets on `IOExceptions`. It also conflates exceptions with empty responses. Not a good example of anything, and not a solution to the problem, whatever it is.

Comment: The socket shutdown procudure is based on tutorials like http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-networking/sockets.html , the IOException handler copied from the code in question to test it, and, yes could and should be optimized.

Comment: @Andrey: The server is written in C. And may be it doesn't work like a java server.

Comment: @julivico aha! So, it is not necessarily writeUTF()/readUTF(). How did you tested server with telnet then?

Comment: Very simple. Connected, request text entered, and than i got the right response. I have followed a tutorial from internet. My program worked for short response and i thought, that it' works.

Comment: I'm trying with `writeBytes` and `readLine`. But i got only two characters instead of the full text with `readLine`.

Comment: I have tried it. The next is null. But i worked now, when i used `writeUTF` and `BufferedReader.readLine()`. Hmm......

Comment: It worked now and I have understood them too. I have voted your answer, but someone has down voted it. I will mark the answer of EJP as the right answer, because he has found my problem with `readUTF`. Thank you very much for your help,  Andrey Lebedenko!!!!! Your help was very helpful

Comment: @AndreyLebedenko There is no shutdown call on the page you linked, or its immediate successor, after which it degenerates into UDP and URLs. I'm not going to trawl through the entire website, but you cannot cite arbitrary third-party Web resources and expect to be accepted. If you found sometihing in an RFC, or the Posix specification, or an official Java specification, you can get traction. As it is, you can't.

Comment: @EJB Let me explain. First, the tutorial linked is just an example of flush/close combination which appears to be considered as good practice. Second, if I use any sort of wrapper around streaming object, I personally prefer to shut it down explicitly and not to rely on it's reaction in brute stream or socket closure, which may or may not be redundant depending on implementation. As per potential socket leak, the final clause is closing socket. Now, since I've answered all questions, could you please explain your concerns from technical perspective and view on best practices in these cases?

Comment: Let *me* explain. 1. `close()` calls `flush()`. See the Javadoc. You can dig up any third-party web material you like, but it does not supervene the Javadoc. It isn't good practice. It is redundant. 2. `shutdown()` is an operation on the socket, not on the stream. It is redundant before `close()`, your preferences notwithstanding. 3. Redundant code Isn't good practice anywhere. It is just redundant. In some cases it is worse than redundant, as it forces things to happen twice, or three times. 4. Your `finally` clause closes the `ServerSocket`, but not the accepted `Socket`, which leaks.

Comment: And there is no relying on implementation here. It is all specified in one place or another.

Comment: @EJP Yes, my bad. Should be flushing wrapper, not the socket. Thanks. Fixed. Socket leak as well. Was somehow under impression that they will be automatically closed on ServerSocket shutdown.

Comment: @julivico It you used `writeUTF()` at one end and `readLine()` at the other end it didn't work. `writeUTF()` writes a 16-bit length word and then the string. `readLine()` doesn't care about the length word, which will appear in the resulting string as garbage, but it blocks until a line terminator is received, and `writeUTF()` doesn't write one. They cannot be used together.

Comment: @AndreyLebedenko Flushing the wrapper doesn't do anything either unless there is a buffered stream in the stack, and there isn't. `DataOutputStream.flush()` does nothing except call the wrapped stream's flush, which in this case is the socket output stream's flush, which does nothing.

Comment: @EJP yes, i known. I have understood it now. I use `write()` and `readLine()`. Is it ok?

Comment: @EJP as I said, in this particular case this particular implementation of this particular class of wrapper doesn't have caching capabilities. However, switch to the `BufferedOutputStream` (which btw implements exactly the same set of interfaces) or something similar -- and voila! -- you have 0 bytes sent on socket.close() if you don't flush. Do you think it is reasonable to flush wrapper? Anyway, this is **test** server part to server test run of the provided code to prove that the idea behind use of writeUTF/readUTF is right. And as far as I can see it reaches it's goal and stays on subject.